# Asp.mvc request validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, html-encode

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application in which I want to set

```
requestValidationMode="4.0"
```

and all areas of the website were a normal user has access have

```
ValidateInput(true)
```

SoI basically html encode all user input and save it encoded in the database. (The site is not meant to work without javascript)

My question is

How should I treat the ***signup***, ***log in*** and ***change password*** functionality ?

Obviously I want to allow the user to insert whichever password he/she wants so,

Is it ok if for the ***password*** field I do ***html encode*** on the client and then ***html decode*** on the server, before saving the password in the database ?

Thank you

Comment: Do not save anything encoded in the database - you should encode per the context it is output (e.g. HTML). Otherwise it would be headache time if you ever wanted to output in another format (e.g. JSON or plain text).

Comment: Saving html in your database doesn't seem like a very good idea either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that passwords aren't ever likely to be displayed in cleartext (or even stored), XSS shouldn't be a concern for passwords.

You can decorate the password property(ies) of your (view) model with [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

I can't think of a reason why the password would need to be echoed back to the client from the server, so the Html sanitization step shouldn't be necessary? (Do password rules validation on the client)

Troy Hunt discusses this [here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/09/do-you-allow-xss-in-your-passwords-you.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Now that you mention it I could just use ValidateInput(false) on change password and login. The only concern I have is with the signup form, which has multiple fields (like user name - which is diplayed in the website); unfortunately [AllowHtml] is not really an option given the code that I've have (it was written some time ago and it would be too much of a headache to change now)

Comment: User names are likely to be echoed on pages, so XSS and Html sanitize checking should be done on these. IMO its just passwords which can be exempt.